# i want to use call button in android web view which is in my html tag <a href="tel:123"></a>

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, android-webview

i want to use phone number link which is in my html tag  when am click on button its shos me error page not found net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME am use  in html code

package com.example.desireservices;

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private WebView myWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.requestFocus();
    myWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://desireservices.in/app");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}